# GPU Processing in R (using openCL)

Tags: r, gpu

I am trying to estimate a parameter by repeated sampling (Monte Carlo simulation). Each time I sample, I have to run a particular operation on a `data.table` object. Here is an example:

```
visits.site <- site.visits.map[site.name %in% sample.sites, 
                              .(length(unique(visits))),
                              by = week]
```

Since the number of samplings often run into millions, this is taking a lot of time. I have made the loop execute in parallel on the multiple cores of the CPU using the `parApply` function. This has appreciably improved the performance. (I ran it over 8 cores). Note: This is an embarrassingly parallel problem.

I want to improve the performance even further by running this on GPU. I have looked at [`gpuR`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gpuR) but I am not sure if it has a function similar to `parApply` for GPUs. Are there any packages that have this functionality in R?

If there are some other ways in which I can improve the performance, please let me know.